# How to generate a Mnemonic in Angular (with npm package bip39 for Solana)

Tags: angular, bitcoin, solana

I'm trying to create a solana wallet from a mnemonic for each of my users. Creating a wallet / keypair from a random keypair works, but I want to create it from a mnemonic so that I can give back the mnemonic to my users, as I think that's the most comfortable for them to import their wallet into e.g. Solflare. I'm using the package `bip39` that seems to come from bitcoin but also work for Solana?

After running `npm install bip39` the import seems to work, but when I try to generate a mnemonic it throws this error.:

```
import * as bip39 from 'bip39';
console.log(bip39);

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MnemonicService {

mnemonic: string = bip39.generateMnemonic();

constructor() { }

}
```

The Error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
    at Hash.CipherBase (index.js:7:1)
    at new Hash (browser.js:9:1)
    at createHash (browser.js:29:1)
    at deriveChecksumBits (index.js:44:1)
    at entropyToMnemonic (index.js:127:1)
    at Object.generateMnemonic (index.js:145:1)
    at new LambdaService (lambda.service.ts:20:44)
    at Object.LambdaService_Factory [as factory] (lambda.service.ts:93:4)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11158:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:10979:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750:1)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28289:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569:1)
```

The `console.log(bip39)` command gives the following, so the import seems to work:

[image]

I found several examples where it seems to work, I can't find what I'm doing wrong:
https://typescript.hotexamples.com/examples/bip39/-/generateMnemonic/typescript-generatemnemonic-function-examples.html
https://github.com/mottolini/ionic-ethereum/blob/master/src/providers/ethereum/ethereum.ts

And I tried it with a simple node.js project, there it works fine:

```
const bip39 = require('bip39')

const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic()
console.log('mnemonic:', mnemonic)
```

So a solution would be to do it in a backend and then send the mnemonic / wallet to Angular... But why is it not working in the Javascript?

Comment: Tried following, but it didn't change anything. At least when running ng serve: https://forum.aeternity.com/t/important-fix-for-angular-typeerror-cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined-at-hash-cipherbase-index-js-7/4153

Comment: i have the same problem. did you find a way to make it work?

Comment: @GervasiusTwinklewinkleson I am having same problem, did you find solution to that?

Comment: @Sanam yes i did, but i can't remember now what it was. i think it might have been using node's Buffer instead of default Buffer. i added this to polyfills.ts : " (window as any).global = window;
 global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
 (window as any).process = {
   version: ''
 }; "