# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') at Hash.CipherBase

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, cryptography, cryptojs

I am using create-hash package (https://github.com/crypto-browserify/createHash) in my code of ionic react application.

I have installed the package using `npm install create-hash`

I am using the function as following:

```
const hash = createHash('sha256')
      .update("entropyBuffer")
      .digest();
```

However, it throws the following error in the browser:

[image]

When I change the algorithm to the following: 'md5', 'rmd160' and 'ripemd160', it works fine. I don't understand what is the problem?

I have looked at the similar queries online but nothing was helpful.

https://github.com/crypto-browserify/cipher-base/issues/11

[How to generate a Mnemonic in Angular (with npm package bip39 for Solana)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816223/how-to-generate-a-mnemonic-in-angular-with-npm-package-bip39-for-solana)

Comment: have you imported create-hash?

Comment: Yes, I have imported create-hash

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the original answer here - [Link](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/cipher-base/issues/10#issuecomment-890863187)

[patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) helped me:

```
npm i patch-package
```

in the package.json add this line:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "patch-package",
}
```

opend the problem file and correct it. In my case:

```
node_modules/cipher-base/index.js


var Buffer = require('safe-buffer').Buffer
var Transform = require('readable-stream').Transform // replacing instead of "stream"
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder
var inherits = require('inherits')

function CipherBase (hashMode) {
...
```

run the command from a root dir of your project:

```
npx patch-package cipher-base
```

it'll create a new folder patches in the root dir and add there this fix. That's all. Commit changes. It'll automaticaly replace code in the node_modules after reinstalling packages